# RegEx Date Format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: regex

Can anyone please tell me if there is something wrong with this regEx:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/
```

I am trying to create a regEx for dates by MM/DD/YYYY, I thought this would cut it but for some reason it is still saying dates that are correct are invalid.

Such as 02/15/2015 , 01/31/2013 , etc. Any day that should be valid is not being validated so I am thinking this regEx is not doing what I was hoping it was doing...

Will anyone take a look at it and see where I may have messed up please?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working as planned? Can you provide samples of dates that are handled incorrectly?

Comment: The days are missing. Try `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])|3[01]\/(19|20)\d{2}$/`. Note: This does not cater for valid dates ( eg. Feb 31st is perfectly acceptable with this regex)

Comment: *it is not working as planned* is not a useful problem description. In what way is it *not working*? We can't see your screen from here. It also helps if you tell us what regex dialect you're using, as there are (sometimes major) differences between them.

Comment: `0[1-9]|1[0-2])`. regex is a lousy tool for number range validation. And not even all that useful, here, when you've got different numbers of days per month to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in RegexBuddy, using it's default PCRE dialect:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

It successfully matches

```
01/01/2014
12/31/2000
07/15/1955
01-01-2012
12.22.1922
```

It fails (correctly) on

```
13/01/2001
12/33/2015
01/01/1200
15.36.1948
01.50.1922
```

Comment: Those are *anchors*, and it seems to me you could test in about 2 seconds to find out if you need them or not. (Try the exact regex I posted, and if it doesn't work add the anchors and try again.) Whether you need anchors or not depends on how specifically you're using the regex and the text content you're attempting to match against.

Comment: Nitpicking note: accepts illegal dates like `04/31/2000`.

Comment: @collapsar: Certainly it does. It also doesn't correctly handle leap years. It certainly meets the somewhat broad criteria defined in the question, however. :-)

Comment: @David: Me? No, because I'm smart enough not to try to use a regex for more complex validations than this; there are much better solutions in most programming languages and libraries. The regex shown is what I use for very rudimentary data entry validation to rule out typos. If you have more complex needs, don't try to use a regex.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this shouldn't be addressed by a regex, mostly due to the complications arising from leap years. Anyway, disregarding this issue by accepting Feb 29th for all years and considering dates from the 20th and 21st century only, we have (pcre syntax; split across multiple lines for easier understanding. fold into a single line by eliminating all leading whitespace in a line):

```
/^
   (
       (0[13578]|1[02])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
     | (0[469]|11)\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)
     | 02\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])
   )
   \/(19|20)\d{2}
$/x
```

[Live test on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/nX9iA0/7).

Comment: Finally we can agree on something!  I appreciate that suggestion very much.

Comment: Tested on https://regex101.com/ (after several useful hints to syntactic errorsby @KenWhite).