# JavaScript Birthday Validation: Regex Format

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

Trying to test out some JS form validation. Not sending this information to any database or anything; just trying to hammer down the format for now. All my regex checks are working fine except for **birth**

It seems as though there is something wrong in the regex check because when I put another check in there with a different format, it works fine. I want them to enter the birthday in mm/dd/yyyy fashion and display the proper error if not. Any help is appreciated!

```
    if(birth == "") {
        printError("birthErr", "Please enter your birthday");
    } else {
        var regex = '/^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/';                 
        if(regex.test(birth) === false) {
            printError("birthErr", "Please enter a valid birthday");
        } else {
            printError("birthErr", "");
            birthErr = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please cut down the code to be [repro] (pay extra attention to the word minimal). It is not necessary to post hundreds of lines of code if it is just about the regex for your birthday. Only the birthday part is more than sufficient!

Comment: Play around with some regex here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to validate date formats dd/mm/YYYY, dd-mm-YYYY, dd.mm.YYYY, dd mmm YYYY, dd-mmm-YYYY, dd/mmm/YYYY, dd.mmm.YYYY with Leap Year Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-formats-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mmm-yyyy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727474/2055998

Comment: @PM77-1 - I have made these changes in the code before however upon submit it still jumps to the confirmation page.

Comment: maybe you can see the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: maybe you can see the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

Your does not validate leap years correctly, you can try to use the regex below, it can use to take dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy.

> ^(?:(?:31(/|-|.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(/|-|.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(/|-|.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(/|-|.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$

You can try this regex [here](https://regexr.com/346hf)